# Cannot turn on external display with xrandr

Tags: video, macintosh, xrandr, display

I'm running Linux on my Macbook Pro with i3 and I have been able to get everything working execpt my external monitor from the HDMI port. xrandr sees the monitor but the monitor still says "no signal" when I configure it in xrandr.

Sometimes when I configure it with `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto` my laptop screen scales down to the moitors resolution but the external monitor still does not turn on.

My /etc/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf looks like this:

```
Selection "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP-2"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSelection

Selection "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI-0"
    Option      "Above" "DP-2"
EndSelection
```

and my `xrandr -q` output looks like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis     y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   2880x1800     59.99*+
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```